# Using the nth element from a list as an input for a function

Tags: r

> *TLDR*: how to take the *nth* element from a list to use it as an input for a function.

I get three different excel files in my mail every day: `Ayyyymmdd.xls`, `Byyyymmdd.xls` and `Cyyyymmdd.xls` (the file names change every day; "*yyyy*" is year, "*mm*" is month and "*dd*" is day) .

I need to read these files in R. To do this, I created a list that changes according to today's date. Today, the list looks as follows:

```
files <- as.list(c("A20180829.xls", "B20180829.xls", "C20180829.xls")
```

I now need to read all three files **separately** (using `lapply` works, but I want to reference only one element at a time). Unfortunately, the following command doesn't work:

```
Atoday <- read.xls(files[1], sheet = 1)            # Doesn't work
Atoday <- read.xls("A20180829.xls", sheet = 1)     # Works
```

My main concern is how to take the *nth* element from a list to use it as an input for a function. The function doesn't need to be `read.xls`, for all I care, it could be `read.csv()`, `fread()`, etc.

Comment: Read all in to one [list-of-frames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272): `alldat <- sapply(files, read.xls, sheet=1, simplify=FALSE)`

Comment: `lapply` or `sapply` will do this, iterating applying a command over the entire list.

Comment: But this is exactly what `lapply` is for: *"take the nth element from a list to use it as an input for a function"*. What do you mean by *"using `lapply` works, but I want to reference only one element at a time"*? `lapply` does only reference only one element at a time. I don't see you have any reason not to use `lapply`.

Comment: Oh, I meant that I specifically did not want to use ´lapply´. I wanted to find a way to refer to just one argument in a list. For example, instead of reading all the files, I wanted to know how to read the 20th file.

Comment: The only reason `read.xls(files[1], ...)` doesn't work is because **[you need `files[[1]` to index into a list](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Lists)**. (Instead of just posting it with "Doesn't work" you should try to figure out why and fix it...)

Comment: I wrote you a canonical question and answer for that [Why does indexing into a list with list instead of list in R not do what you would expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55859382/why-does-indexing-into-a-list-with-list-n-instead-of-listn-in-r-not-do-wha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `list`, so we need `[[` to extract the `list` element.  The `[` is still a `list` of `length` 1

```
read.xls(files[[1]], sheet = 1)
```

---

We can find the difference with `str` or by typing it in the console

```
files[1]
#[[1]]
#[1] "A20180829.xls"

files[[1]]
#[1] "A20180829.xls"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

I don't understand the syntax though. ´files[1]´ returns a list of 1. Why does adding an additional [] turn it into a character string?

Comment: @ArturoSbr  As I mentioned,  the files is a `list`.  Extracting elements of `list` is done with `[[`.  If you use a single `[`, it still will not be able to extract that `list`.  Please check `?Extract`